# How to represent a function as a solution of a question

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

When a question is asking to find a function of a curve where $f(x)$ is the curve function and the stem of the question is as follows:

If the slope of the tangent to a curve at any point $(x,y)$ on it equals to  $6e^x+2$ and $f(ln5)=1$, find $f(x)$.

Is the answer to this question should/must be in the form of:

$f(x)=6e^{x}+2x-29-2\ln{5}$

or could I just write:

$6e^{x}+2x-29-2\ln{5}$

Without mentioning $f(x)$.

**So here is my question, is not mentioning $f(x)$ in the answer of this question is mathematically wrong?**

Comment: Well, if you do write $f(x)=...$ in the answer, that certainly can't be mathematically wrong. Best to err on the side of caution in these matters methinks.

Answer (score 2):

Mention $f(x)$ is correct. 
Do you ever write a sentence without subject?

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem asked you to **find $f(x)$**, you have to.. find $f(x)$.

That is the solution is:

$$f(x) = \ldots$$